Image upload problem in django-ckeditor-5
I use django-ckeditor-5 in my Django project
These are my ckeditor settings in settings.py
CKEDITOR_5_CONFIGS = {
    'extends': {
        'blockToolbar': [
            'paragraph', 'heading1', 'heading2', 'heading3',
            '|',
            'bulletedList', 'numberedList',
            '|',
            'blockQuote',
        ],
        'toolbar': {
            'items': ['heading', '|', 'outdent', 'indent', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'link', 'underline', 'strikethrough',
                      'subscript', 'superscript', 'highlight', '|', 'insertImage', 'fileUpload',
                      'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'todoList', '|', 'blockQuote', '|',
                      'fontSize', 'fontColor', 'fontBackgroundColor', 'mediaEmbed', 'removeFormat',
                      'insertTable'],
            'shouldNotGroupWhenFull': True
        },
        'image': {
            'toolbar': [
                "imageTextAlternative",
                "|",
                "imageStyle:alignLeft",
                "imageStyle:alignRight",
                "imageStyle:alignCenter",
                "imageStyle:side",
                "|",
                "toggleImageCaption",
                "|"
            ],
            'styles': [
                'full',
                'side',
                'alignLeft',
                'alignRight',
                'alignCenter',
            ]

        },
        'table': {
            'contentToolbar': ['tableColumn', 'tableRow', 'mergeTableCells',
                               'tableProperties', 'tableCellProperties'],
            'tableProperties': {
                'borderColors': customColorPalette,
                'backgroundColors': customColorPalette
            },
            'tableCellProperties': {
                'borderColors': customColorPalette,
                'backgroundColors': customColorPalette
            }
        },
        'heading': {
            'options': [
                {'model': 'paragraph', 'title': 'Paragraph', 'class': 'ck-heading_paragraph'},
                {'model': 'heading1', 'view': 'h1', 'title': 'Heading 1', 'class': 'ck-heading_heading1'},
                {'model': 'heading2', 'view': 'h2', 'title': 'Heading 2', 'class': 'ck-heading_heading2'},
                {'model': 'heading3', 'view': 'h3', 'title': 'Heading 3', 'class': 'ck-heading_heading3'}
            ]
        },
    },
}

CKEDITOR_5_ALLOW_ALL_FILE_TYPES = True
CKEDITOR_5_FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSION = "authenticated"

This is the field where I used ckeditor: CKEditor5Field('content', config_name='news')
But when I upload an image from my PC through admin panel, I get this error:
This problem exists for all files, not just images

If anyone knows, please help

you need to implement the functionality to how the upload work. normally there should be a backend api to call when you upload file.
